# How to relate 3 tables using primary key concepts

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make 3 entity,Class,Subject and Examination,what is the best possible way to do that,what should be my primary table and primary key that I will use as foreign ky in other two tables

Answer (score 0):

The question is way generic. I assume it's from the point of view of a school. Given that:

- you can have as many classes as you want for each Subject
- you can have as many examinations as you want for each Subject
- classes and examinations are not related

You'll have

- a Subject entity, with no foreign keys
- a Class entity, depending on Subject
- an Examination entity, depending on Subject

Which will produce this SQL stub:

```
CREATE TABLE Subject (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Class (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- some other defining columns here
    id_subject INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_subject) REFERENCES Subject(id)
);
```

You'll need the same for the examination. As a side note, you may want to have the foreign key in Class nullable, because there may not be a subject for some classes (e.g. free time? missing teacher?), but you'll definitely want to have a not-null constraint on the foreign key in Examination.

Since this looks like an assignment, I won't go into further details...

EDIT: In the case your "class" entity means the schoolyear you would relate Class and Subject with an additional table, since this relation becomes N x M:

```
CREATE TABLE Subject_Class (
    id_class INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_subject INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_class, id_subject),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_class) REFERENCES Class(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_subject) REFERENCES Subject(id)
);
```

and you would remove the foreign key from the Class table.

Comment: Thanks,but my problem is suppose for a class,take it as class 8,they have 5 subjects English,Math,Life Science,Physical Science,History. then how can I relate with the id? means for class 5, I have to add each subject one by one?

Comment: In this case you would relate Class and Subject with an additional table, since this relation becomes N x M: editing my answer.